# How to set time_t function call to a passed-by time_t value?

Tags: c++, class, lvalue, time-t

I had a quick question about setting up values for function calls of type_t. In my project I have a parameterized constructor (within a function) of:

`ShippingStatus s(location, status, timeUpdated)`

and in this class there is a simple get function of

```
time_t ShippingStatus::m_getTime() {
//TimeUpdated already initialized
return TimeUpdated;
}
```

Now, the values for `location, status, timeUpdated` are all passed-by reference within this main function, and I am attempting to do something like `s.m_getTime() = timeUpdated;` but am getting an error of:

```
expression must be a modifiable lvalue
```

I was able to do the same operation with `location` and `status` using similar get functions, but why won't it work with time_t? Is there any way around this?

Comment: Return *by reference*? If you want to modify `TimeUpdate` at least.

Comment: You should post actual, minimal code that reproduces your error if you want help here.  The devil's often in the detail.  Your posted code's obviously not taken from your actual program: `ShippingStatus s(string::location,` shouldn't have `::` in there.  If you can make an error like that, we can't assume much about what other errors you might or might not have made.

Comment: To be by reference you need to change the return typr to `time_t&`  your constructor doesn't look lika a valid C++

Comment: Sorry, fixed up the constructor to be what's actually in my code. I'll try out the reference return type. Is there somewhere I can read up on why return by reference works in this case over regular return?

Comment: Because return by reference returns an alias to the variable that you return, while return by value effectively returns a value. Assigning to it would be the same as if you would do `5 = 9` and then expect that to compile